# Slack: Is it possible to initiate an API call using user input from slack to another system?

Tags: python, api, slack

I have been asked to try and get something working in our slack environment for our campus locations to use. The goal is to have a user input the location which would initiate the API call to the other system and return some basic high level system health stats.

I am familiar with how to setup webhooks to slack, just not sure if it's possible to do this or not with slack.

Answer (score 0):

The slack API (https://api.slack.com/) is fairly complex to get set up, but it will do what you want once you get there.  It has a web API that you can register to receive hooks from when things appear in messages or chats, for example, and thus you can trigger things to run when people say certain things, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a user to input a location on slack, and based on their input to make an API call to a different service.

You have several options to get the input from the user:

- You can create a bot that the user can [chat with](https://api.slack.com/authentication/basics)
- You can create a shortcut or workflow that users can use to fill some [kind of form](https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals)
- You can allow for interactions on your application's [home page](https://api.slack.com/tutorials/app-home-with-modal)

All these options will get slack to send a payload to some endpoint you define. You will have to set up some basic back end to handle this and call your external APIs from.

I'm currently working on a similar project and recommend using some serverless, fast setup. I have opted for Lambda and API gateway for this. The experience is:

1. The user goes to the app home page and presses a button
2. The user gets a form to fill
3. On form submission, slack sends a payload to an endpoint set via API gateway
4. API gateway summons a lambda function
5. The function parses and validates the payload, and ultimately makes a request to my external API

Comment: I am also looking for a similar use case. will you be able to complete that project? Do you have any progress on that!